# Jquery: select a child div at its index inside a parent div

Tags: jquery

If I have:

```
<div id='parent'> 
  <table> 
        <tr> 
            <td> 
                <div id='child1'></div> 
            </td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
             <td> 
                <div id='child2'></div> 
             </td> 
        </tr> 
    </table>
 </div>
```

I tried: $('#parent> table > tr:eq(1) > div');

I would like to select a certain child div at its index. For example, I would like to select the second child div child2. A trivial solution is:

```
var div2 = $('#child2');
```

But I would rather like to do so with the *parent* div:

```
var div2 = $('#parent div')...get(1); // 1 is the index.
```

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using the [`:eq()` selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/GLECb/):

```
$("#parent > div:eq(1)")
```

Or if it's dynamic and you need to pass it in, use [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/GLECb/1/):

```
$("#parent > div").eq(1)
```

In both of these we're using `1` because it's a 0-based index, so `1` is the 2nd child.

Comment: Is the return value the OP's dom element or a jquery object?

Comment: @Rabid - It's a jQuery object, e.g. you could call `.addClass("active")` at the end.  I don't follow on this part though "the OP's dom element"...not sure what you mean there?  The OP never mentioned wanting it one way or another (note that in his example is *is* a jQuery object though), *usually* you'd want the jQuery wrapper version.

Comment: Ah yes referring to his example that is the case, good point.

Comment: Hi Nick Carver,

Thanks for the answer. It should work as I stated above but when I check it again, my structure is different, it is:

<div id='parent'>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
   <div id='child1'></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
   <div id='child2'></div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>
   <div id='child3'></div>
</td>
</tr>
</div>

I tried: $('#parent> table > tr:eq(1) > div'); but it is undefined?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JoesyXHN - A `<tbody>` gets inserted in there, so the `table > tr` won't work, try using just a space :)

Comment: I am sorry, what did you mean with using just a space? :=)

Thanks!

Comment: @JoesyXHN - Remove the `>` between `table` and `tr`  in your selector, so it reads `table tr` instead of `table > tr`, make sense?

Comment: @Nick Craver: yes, it is working ;) I altered it a bit. I made a sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/VLhdw/ Could you please explain me when and why we need to use '>' ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JoesyXHN - You don't usually *need* to, only if you want *only* direct children (e.g. if you may have child tables you want to ignore for example). For your example you can leave all the `>` out :)

Answer (score 0):

You will want the [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) function

E.g:

> $('#parent').children()[1];

Comment: I was wrong with my structure, any ideas how to deal with it now? 

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [:nth-child()](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) selector.

E.g.

```
$('#parent div:nth-child(2)');
```

**Update due to comment**

```
$('#parent > div:nth-child(2)');
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if the children have children, this may select them as well (if they have more than 1 `<div>` as siblings).

Comment: I was wrong with my structure, any ideas how to deal with it now? 

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of simple ways to do this:

```
var div2 = $("#parent > div:eq(1)")
```

When using the "eq" selector, note that it is zero-based, so this will, in fact, select the 2nd div within the #parent div.

A second way is:

```
var div2 = $("#parent > div:nth-child(2)")
```

The "nth-child" selector is not zero based, so "nth-child(2)" will also select the 2nd div. You can also select odd and even divs via "nth-child(even)" and "nth-child(odd)". It will even evaluate equations in the parenthesis - you can read more about it in the jQuery documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).

Comment: I was wrong with my structure, any ideas how to deal with it now? 

Thanks in advance.